# CMake sdl-config

Tags: cmake, sdl

Is there a way to use sdl-config in CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just use `find_program()` to find it and `execute_process()` to run it and capture its output. If you actually want to test for SDL and use it in your project, CMake comes with `FindSDL.cmake`, so you could just put `find_package(SDL)` in your `CMakeLists.txt` and then just access `SDL_CFLAGS` and so on directly.